# Trying to find how similar one column is to another in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, metrics

I am trying to calculate accuracy rate.

I have a pandas dataframe with numerous columns of data.

I have one column of predicted churns and one column of true churns for every customer.

Is there a way to calculate the accuracy metric and other metrics just between the two columns? Both columns are only binary of 0 as no churn and 1 as churn.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html. See the bottom set for a list of most typical distance measurements between two Boolean vectors.

Comment: Though, since you mention you have a predicted column, you may be more interested in calculating the ROC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic from your predicted probability, and then scoring your prediction in terms of the Area Under the ROC

Comment: @ALollz OP is clear in that both columns are binary (i.e. no probabilities), hence ROC is not applicable

Comment: @desertnaut it depends what type model is behind the prediction that spit out 1/0. If there are truly no probabilities with an arbitrary threshold underlying the classification, then sure ignore it. But there's little to go on for this question...

Comment: @ALollz question is clearly and simply about two binary columns in a pandas dataframe; given that, starting to imagine what may be "behind" the prediction column is pure speculation and arguably irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is obviously many ways you can measure accuracy of a prediction against known answers. Since you tagged this with machine learning and python, I suggest using a confusion matrix (aka error matrix) as a first pass. The scikit-learn python library has a module that you can use:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = ...
y_pred = ...
confusion_matrix( y_true, y_pred )
```

source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html